# C# Lambda puzzling behaviour

Tags: c#, clr, lambda

```
Func<Classification, string> test1 = c => c.Id = "x"; 
Func<Classification, string> test2 = c => { return c.Id = "x";};
```

I've worked with lambda's for nearly a year or so now and fairly reasonable with them, but today I was looking at [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/) and seen a weird Func that didn't seem to match the examples. I had play anyway and it checks out but I don't understand why the above compiles let alone runs. We are doing an assignment and thus the expression doesn't evaluate to anything, right??? or not

So I thought maybe something I've missed related to lambda, so I tried something else:

```
    [Test]
    public void AmIGoingMad()
    {
        Assert.That(Test(),Is.Null); // not sure what to expect - compile fail?
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        string subject = "";
        return subject = "Matt";
    }
```

Sure enough `AmIGoingMad` fails and "Matt" is actually returned.

Why do we have this behavior? Where is this documented? Is it purely a syntactic shortcut?

I feel like I missed something fundamental in my understanding of lambda or even C#.

Feeling dumb.

Comment: OMG, I've been doing this for years..  Just never thought.. I'll be damned. 

IPerson person = null;
if((instance as Person) != null) { }

Comment: I think you need to clarify. "Where is this documented?" <-- what is "this" in that sentence? "Is it purely..." <-- again, what is "it"? "this behavior", which behavior? That return returns a value? That = assigns a value? That "Matt" is not null?

Comment: Sorry. if I knew the definiton I could of been clearer. i.e. "assignment chaining" as Joel/Eric point out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An assignment statement has a return value--that value is that which was assigned.  Even C had this, so you could chain together assignments like the following:

```
a = b = c = d = 10;
```

The assignment to d has the return value of 10 which gets assigned to c, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is assignment chaining, something that goes way back to C/C++.  It's there to support this scenario:

```
int a = b = c = 0;
```

Or somewhere I actually use it:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string filePath)
{
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
       string line;
       while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)  // <-----
       {
          yield return line;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works because the assignment `c.Id = "x"` evaluates to the value of "x". You can use this for example if you want to assign and check a value in one statement (which some people consider bad practice) like this:

```
string s;
if((s = SomeFunction()) != null) { \\do something with s }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the assignment returns a value itself.

You could also take advantage of it like this:

```
private List<string> theList;
public List<string> LazyList
{
  get { return theList ?? (theList = new List<string>()); }
}
```

Comment: This breaks the purity assumption of property getters (no side effects).

Comment: @280Z28 - This is a valid example of a lazy loading property. In .Net4 they've added Lazy<> to easily make this type of property threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

You post code that looks like you've misunderstood the difference between `=` and `==`, and then explicitly comment that you want it to use `=` which is the assignment operator.

Let me ask you a question instead:

Why would you want or expect this to not compile?

```
Assert.That(Test(),Is.Null); // not sure what to expect - compile fail?
```

Basically, you're doing this:

```
String temp = Test();
Assert.That(temp, Is.Null);
```